# Are there any applications of the "imaginary derivative" $D^i$ operator?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives, differential-operators, fractional-calculus

Where $D$ is the normal differential operator, $D f(x) = \frac{d}{dx} f(x)$, $D^n f(x) = (\frac{d}{dx})^n f(x)$, we can define, for example, the "half-derivative" $D^\frac{1}{2}$ such that $D^\frac{1}{2}D^\frac{1}{2} = D$.

If you work through the details, it turns out that, for real $\alpha$,

$$D^\alpha x^n = \frac{n!}{(n-\alpha)!}x^{n-\alpha}$$

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMalym_n8zM), Dr Peyam extends this to complex $\alpha$, constructing the "imaginary derivative" $D^i$.

At the end of this, he says he knows of no applications of this operator.

Can you think of any?

Comment: See also the [wiki page on fractional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus)